# jQueryUI datepicker formatted date range clearing its partner on new date

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, date, datepicker, date-formatting

I have two input fields, displaying a **from** and a **to** month/year. No date should be selected, only the month and year are actually relevant, so first day in the month is used.

They also have an alt field each, to send a proper value to the server.

However, whenever a date has been selected in one field, and the **min** or **maxDate** gets set on the other, that one will clear its field.
I have done some extensive debugging of the values passed, and have only been able to narrow it down to the **formatting** of the date being the issue. I can't seem to think of why it would be, however, with the extra code used, to parse and create a proper date.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ntGT4/1/)

Line 13, and 40 triggers the error:

```
$('#user_range2').datepicker('option', 'minDate', $('#user_range1').datepicker('getDate'));
```

I experimented with several jQuery versions on jsfiddle, and none appeared to have a fix.

Does anyone know how I can keep the formatting, and get it to work as intended?

**Update**

I've narrowed it down to the issue. Since there's no date in the format, the following line will throw an exception (from jqueryui.js@*parseDate()*):

```
date = this._daylightSavingAdjust(new Date(year, month - 1, day));
    if (date.getFullYear() !== year || date.getMonth() + 1 !== month || date.getDate() !== day) {
        throw "Invalid date"; // E.g. 31/02/00
    }
```

Unless there's a way to circumvent that, it seems to be impossible to not have a date in the format, when wanting to limit the range of two fields.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:

From date:

```
$( "#datepicker_start" ).datepicker({
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
            $( "#datepicker_end" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
        }
});
```

To date:

```
$( "#datepicker_end" ).datepicker({
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
            $( "#datepicker_start" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
        }
});
```